# pythonでの結果をExcelに出力する方法

Tags: python, python3

pythonでwebスクレイピングをして、その検索ワードや検索結果をexcelに出力したいと考えています。

excelでの出力の例としてこのような形を構想しています。
[image: excel]

ですが今のpythonでのプログラムを実行すると
[image: excel]

このような結果になってしまい、思った通りに出力されません。
以下がコードなのですが、なにか解決策があればご教示お願い致します

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import openpyxl as op
import datetime
import time


def change_window(browser):
    all_handles = set(browser.window_handles)
    switch_to = all_handles - set([browser.current_window_handle])
    assert len(switch_to) == 1
    browser.switch_to.window(*switch_to)


def main():
    for i in range(1,9):
        wb = op.load_workbook('一般名称.xlsx')
        ws = wb.active
        word = ws['A'+str(i)].value

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\/chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get("https://www.pmda.go.jp/PmdaSearch/kikiSearch/")
        #id検索
        elem_search_word = driver.find_element_by_id("txtName")
        elem_search_word.send_keys(word)
        #name検索
        elem_search_btn = driver.find_element_by_name('btnA')
        elem_search_btn.click()
        change_window(driver)

        #print(driver.page_source)
        cur_url = driver.current_url
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
        #print(cur_url)

        has_pdf_link = False
        print(word)

        wb = op.load_workbook('URL_DATA.xlsx')
        ws = wb.active
        ws['C'+str(i)].value = word

        for a_tag in soup.find_all('a'):
            link_pdf = (urljoin(cur_url, a_tag.get('href')))
            #link_PDFから文末がpdfと文中にPDFが入っているものを抽出
            #print(word)

            if (not link_pdf.lower().endswith('.pdf')) and ('/ResultDataSetPDF/' not in link_pdf):
                continue
            if ('searchhelp' not in link_pdf):
                has_pdf_link = True
                print(link_pdf)
                ws['B'+str(i)].value = link_pdf

        if not has_pdf_link:
            print('False')
            ws['B'+str(i)].value = has_pdf_link

            time.sleep(2)
            time_data = datetime.datetime.today()

            ws['A'+str(i)].value = time_data

        #wb = op.load_workbook('URL_DATA.xlsx')
        #ws = wb.active
            #時間を記入
        #ws['A'+str(i)].value = time_data
        #URLを記入
        #ws['B'+str(i)].value = link_pdf
        #一般名称を記入
        #ws['C'+str(i)].value = word

        wb.save('URL_DATA.xlsx')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

すみません。動作確認はできていませんが、
1ページに複数のPDFリンクがある場合もあるため、
1検索ワードに対して、n個のリンクがあることを考慮するように修正しました。

以下`main()`のみ抜粋します。

```
def main():
    # 1ページに複数のPDFリンクがある場合もあるため、
    # 1検索ワードに対して、n個のリンクがあることを考慮し
    # 独立した行番号を用意
    ridx = 1
    for i in range(1,9):
        wb = op.load_workbook('一般名称.xlsx')
        ws = wb.active
        word = ws['A'+str(i)].value

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\/chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get("https://www.pmda.go.jp/PmdaSearch/kikiSearch/")
        #id検索
        elem_search_word = driver.find_element_by_id("txtName")
        elem_search_word.send_keys(word)
        #name検索
        elem_search_btn = driver.find_element_by_name('btnA')
        elem_search_btn.click()
        change_window(driver)

        #print(driver.page_source)
        cur_url = driver.current_url
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
        #print(cur_url)

        has_pdf_link = False
        print(word)

        wb = op.load_workbook('URL_DATA.xlsx')
        ws = wb.active

        # ページを解析した日時
        time_data = datetime.datetime.today()

        # 全てのaタグを調査
        for a_tag in soup.find_all('a'):
            link_pdf = (urljoin(cur_url, a_tag.get('href')))
            #link_PDFから文末がpdfと文中にPDFが入っているものを抽出
            #print(word)

            if (not link_pdf.lower().endswith('.pdf')) and ('/ResultDataSetPDF/' not in link_pdf):
                continue
            # リンクあり
            if ('searchhelp' not in link_pdf):
                print(link_pdf)
                ws['A'+str(ridx)].value = time_data
                ws['B'+str(ridx)].value = link_pdf
                # 最初のリンク行のみ検索ワードを記録
                if not has_pdf_link:
                    ws['C'+str(ridx)].value = word
                has_pdf_link = True
                ridx += 1

        if not has_pdf_link:
            print('False')
            ws['A'+str(ridx)].value = time_data
            ws['B'+str(ridx)].value = has_pdf_link
            ws['C'+str(ridx)].value = word
            ridx += 1

        # サーバーへの負荷防止??
        time.sleep(2)

        #wb = op.load_workbook('URL_DATA.xlsx')
        #ws = wb.active
            #時間を記入
        #ws['A'+str(i)].value = time_data
        #URLを記入
        #ws['B'+str(i)].value = link_pdf
        #一般名称を記入
        #ws['C'+str(i)].value = word

        wb.save('URL_DATA.xlsx')
```